# javascript function callback after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code

```
function confirm(){

    okBtn.on('click', function(){
        // return true from confirm function
    });
    cancelBtn.on('click', function(){
        // return false from confirm function
    });
}


if(confirm()){
    // make something. I need to keep this code here, not in confirm function
}
```

I need to execute callback after okBtn or cancelBtn are clicked. I need to keep callback code not in function, coz I have a lot of cases that use this function.

Comment: What behaviour are you trying to achieve? The pattern used here will never work in JS for multiple reasons.

Comment: There is already one function `"confirm("message")"` which do the same.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have some cases, where I need to show a confirm popup. If it's confirmed, I need to continue my code, if no - stop it.

Comment: search about `"JavaScript confirm"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the `confirm` function accept the callback and invoke it inside the event handlers:

```
function confirm(callback){
    okBtn.on('click', function(){
        callback(true);
    });
    cancelBtn.on('click', function(){
        callback(false);
    });
}


confirm(function(result) {
    // make something. I need to keep this code here, not in confirm function
});
```

But there is no way to deal with event handlers synchronously (like you seem intend to do). The very reason why you have to *bind event handlers* is that you don't know when the events occur. Instead you have to *react* to the event. You have to get used to this way of coding, there is no way around.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an extra function, you could simply create a flag and change it based on user action:

```
var confirm_flag; // this is undefined, which means that no actions have been taken

okBtn.on('click', function(){
    validate(true);
});
cancelBtn.on('click', function(){
    validate(false);
});
```

Then, based on the user input, you can determine which course of action you want to take:

```
function validate(flag) {
    if(flag) {
        alert("okBtn has been clicked, it's safe to continue");
    }else{
        alert("Not good!");
    }
}
```

If you want to use the return value from a confirm popup, you can simply assign the `Window confirm()` function to a variable - if the user clicks ok, it will return true

```
var x = confirm('Is it safe?'); // will pop a confirm dialog box and return true if ok is pressed and false if cancel is pressed
```

Comment: I guess the important question is when/where is `if(confirm_flag) {... }` executed.

Comment: He can place that if statement right before the action that he wants to take if the user confirmed. Basically, he checks that before executing one of his functions, for example.

Comment: That implies I could put it just after the event handler binding (which won't work).

Comment: Indeed. It would be best to wrap the functionality in a function and then call that function when a certain event happens. Thanks for pointing it out :) I rushed it a bit. I just edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/abwzq32s/

```
html 

<button type="button" id='button1'>confirm</button>
<button type="button" id='button2'>cancel</button>



js 

$('#button1').click(function(){
confirm(true);
});
$('#button2').click(function(){
    confirm(false);
});

function confirm(check){
    if(check){
        alert('ok');
    }else{
        alert('cancel');
    }
}
```

I did a small sample for you. You can either write your code inside the if condition or call another function if your function is really long

Answer (score -2):

As per my understanding what you want is to execute some code only when the user click on the okBtn and some code when the user click on cancelBtn. If that you can change your code in this way

```
function confirm(callback)
{

    okBtn.on('click', function(){
        // return true to the callback
        callback(true)
    });
    cancelBtn.on('click', function(){

        // return false to the callback
         callback(false)
    });
}
confirm(function(confirmed){
    if(confirmed)
    {
    // make something
    }
    else
    {
    // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: How is that different from my answer?

Comment: Sorry, Its not different, when i started writing the answer, your answer was not posted, after posting the answer i saw you post